# Can we create/mutate several new columns at once in tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

Let me clarify I am not looking at `mutate_at` or `mutate(across(..., ...))` type of syntax here.  I just want to know how to create several new columns at once inside tidyverse pipe syntax.

Let us assume the case of `iris` dataset.

I want to create say 10 (or 100 or more) new columns having a criteria like this.

- first new column(variable) say `V1` is just `Petal.Length * 1`,
- second new col say `V2` is `Petal.Length * 2`
- and so on upto say `V10` `Petal.Length * 10`

without explicitly writing the names and formula for each of these columns, which may be cumbersome If I want to create say 100 new columns.

Comment: Very helpful ques and answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `map` functions :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- iris %>% head
value <- 1:5

bind_cols(df, 
     map_dfc(value, ~df %>% transmute(!!paste0('col', .x) := Petal.Length * .x)))

#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa  1.4  2.8  4.2  5.6  7.0
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa  1.4  2.8  4.2  5.6  7.0
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa  1.3  2.6  3.9  5.2  6.5
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa  1.5  3.0  4.5  6.0  7.5
#5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa  1.4  2.8  4.2  5.6  7.0
#6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa  1.7  3.4  5.1  6.8  8.5
```

In base R, this can be done with `lapply` :

```
df[paste0('col', value)] <- lapply(value, `*`, df$Petal.Length)
```

Comment: If we are creating names of object iteratively, do we have to use `:=`?

Comment: Yes, if the column names is dependent on the value in the loop and/or is a string we have to use `:=`.

Comment: One more question @Ronak, what's the use of `!!` here? and why doesn't `mutate` work here?  I tried but its so confusing

Comment: 1. `!!` is used to have a variable column name on LHS. See this example, `k <- "n"` and check the name of the new column name in `df %>% mutate(k = 1)` vs `df %>% mutate(!!k := 1)`. 2.`mutate` works here as well but with `mutate` you get the entire dataframe back along with the new column and when we combine that with `map_dfc` all the columns get duplicated which is not what we need. `transmute` returns only one column in each iteration.

Comment: Very well explained @Ronak.